# Is the establishment of the validity of this argument correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

I am trying to show that the following argument is valid.

- There is an email that is sent but it is not saved in the inbox.
- All emails are saved in the inbox or the inbox is full.
- If the inbox is full, then all emails are lost.
- Therefore, some email is lost.

---

Let the universe of discourse be the emails.

$P(x):\;x$ is sent.

$S(x):\;x$ is saved in the inbox.

$L(x):\;x$ is lost.

$Q:$ Inbox is full.

\begin{align}
 &1.\;  \exists\;(P(x)\; \land \;\lnot\;S(x))  \\
 &2.\; P(c)\;\land\;\lnot\;S(c)\;for\;some\;c \\
&3.\; \forall x\;S(x)\;\lor\;Q \\
&4. \; Q\;\rightarrow\;\forall x\;L(x) \\
&5. \; \lnot Q\;\lor\;\forall x\;L(x) \\ 
&6.\;\forall x\;S(x)\;\lor\;\forall\;L(x) \\
&7.\; S(c)\; \lor \; L(c) \\
&8. \; \lnot \;S(c) \\
&9.\; L(c) \\
&10. \; \exists x\; L(x) \\
\end{align}

Comment: Line 1. should have an $x$ right after $\exists$. Line 2 should say $\exists x (\neg S(x))$  an inference from Line 1. Lines 7. and 8, should be replaced by the single line $\neg \forall x (S(x))$, inferred from Line 2.Line 6 needs editing. to $\forall x (S(x))\lor \forall y L(y)$. Line 9., inferred from 6. and the new 7.-8. should be \forall x (L(x). Line 10 is deduced from line 9. and Line 2, that is, $\exists x (\neg S(x)\land \forall y (L(y))\to \exists x (L(x)$ because we can't infer $\exists x (L(x) )$ only from $\forall x (L(x)).$ We need to know  some $x$ exists (from line 1 or 2)

Comment: You should also include $\implies$  and $\iff$ wherever applicable, so that it can be seen how the assertions are obtained. Especially Line 6'

Comment: @user254665 How can you infer $\exists x (\lnot S(x))$ from line 1 ? The existential quantifier can not be distributed over conjunction.

Comment: $(\exists x\;(a(x)\land \neg b(x)\;)\to \exists x\;(\neg b(x).$  If there exists a horse which is brown and does not eat mice then there exists a horse which does not eat mice.